# finding maximum weight subgraph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, approximation

My graph is as follows:

[image: My graph]

I need to find a maximum weight subgraph.

The problem is as follows:

There are n Vectex clusters, and in every Vextex cluster, there are some vertexes. For two vertexes in different Vertex cluster, there is a weighted edge, and in the same Vextex cluster, there is no edge among vertexes. Now I
want to find a maximum weight subgraph by finding only one vertex in each 
Vertex cluster. And the total weight is computed by adding all weights of the edges between the selected vertex. I add a picture to explain the problem. Now I know how to model this problem by ILP method. However, I do not know how to solve it by an approximation algorithm and how to get its approximation ratio.

Could you give some solutions and suggestions?

Thank you very much. If any unclear points in this description, 
please feel free to ask.

Comment: If you can model it as an ILP, did you try to relax some variables/constraints ? It's a direct way to approximate, without even needing to think about an approximation algorithm.

Comment: Yes, we can relax it by replacing the x_u \in {0,1} by x_u <= 1. But after getting the value of x_u, we need to transform it to the integer to satisfy ILP constraints. However, I cannot think a good rounding solution and get its appro-ratio.

Comment: For the rounding, I'd choose the max value among the `x_u` that belong to the same cluster (give it 1, and 0 to all others). As for the approx ratio, my instinct tells me that this problem will not admit a `alpha`-approx, for any `alpha` (for now I can think only of a`1/k`-approx, k the number of clusters, when using a perfect matching algo to choose candidates).

Comment: Do you know about the [unique games conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_games_conjecture) ? I think you could somehow prove the inexistence of a polynomial approx algo by showing that if there exists one, then it also proves that UGC is false. Which is more than enough, because the UGC is one of the big conjectures of our time in computing complexity. And a very remarquable one, half the computer scientists believe it's true, the other half believes it's false.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can understand the former part, and I agree there is no alpha-approx. But I cannot understand how to get the 1/k-approx by perfect matching. A vertex in perfect matching can only be connected with only one vertex. But in this question, a vertex needs to be connected with other k-1 vertexes. Could you describe your method in detail? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can find an `alpha`-approx for this problem, for any `alpha`. That is because if such an approximation exists, then it would also prove that the [unique games conjecture(UGC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_games_conjecture) is false. And disproving (or proving) the UGC is a rather big feat :-)
(and I'm actually among the UGC believers, so I'd say it's impossible :p)

The reduction is quite straightforward, since any UGC instance can be described as your problem, with weights of `0` or `1` on edges.

What I can see as polynomial approximation is a `1/k`-approx (`k` the number of clusters), using a maximum weight perfect matching (PM) algorithm (we suppose the number of clusters is even, if it's odd just add a 'useless' one with 1 vertex, 0 weights everywhere).

First, you need to build a new graph. One vertex per cluster. The weight of the edge `u, v` has the weight `max w(e)` for `e` edge from cluster `u` to cluster `v`. Run a max weight PM on this graph.

You then can select one vertex per cluster, the one that corresponds to the edge selected in the PM.
The total weight of the solution extracted from the PM is at least as big as the weight of the PM (since it contains the edges of the PM + other edges).

And then you can conclude that this is a `1/k` approx, because if there exists a solution to the problem that is more than `k` times bigger than the PM weight, then the PM was not maximal.

The explanation is quite short (*lapidaire* I'd say), tell me if there is one part you don't catch/disagree with.

Edit: Equivalence with UGC: unique label cover explained.
Think of a UGC instance. Then, every node in the UGC instance will be represented by a cluster, with as many nodes in the cluster as there are colors in the UGC instance. Then, create edge with weight `0` if they do not correspond to an edge in the UGC, or if it correspond to a 'bad color match'. If they correspond to a good color match, then give it the weight 1.
Then, if you find the optimal solution to an instance of your problem, it means it corresponds to an optimal solution to the corresponding UGC instance.
So, if UGC holds, it means it is NP-hard to approximate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your so detailed answer and it is very helpful !  I have understood how to obtain 1/k ratio. But I am not very understand how to reduce UGC problems to this question by setting weight as 0 or 1. For example, in unique label color problem, the colors of vertexes should be unique and should satisfy the edge constrains. However, in this question we don’t have the unique constrain, which indicates we don’t care the type of vertex in every Vertex Cluster and just find a maximum weights. Could you describe it by more details...I cannot catch it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've edited the answer to detail more the correspondence with the UGC.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new graph G'=(V',E') as follows and then solve (or approximate) the maximum stable set problem on G'.

Corresponding to each edge a-b in E(G), introduce a vertex v_ab in V'(G') where its weight is equal to the weight of the edge a-b.

Connect all of vertices of V'(G') to each other except for the following ones.

1. The vertex v_ab is not connected to the vertex v_ac, where vertices b and c are in different clusters in G. In this manner, we can select both of these vertices in an stable set of G' (Hence, we can select both of the corresponding edges in G)
2. The vertex v_ab is not connected to the vertex v_cd, where vertices a, b, c and d are in different clusters in G. In this manner, we can select both of these vertices in an stable set of G' (Hence, we can select both of the corresponding edges in G)

Finally, I think you can find an alpha-approximation for this problem. In other words, in my opinion the Unique Games Conjecture is wrong due to the [1.999999-approximation algorithm](https://vixra.org/abs/2107.0045) which I proposed for the vertex cover problem.